# How could other people know that I'm using GPLed libraries in my application?

Tags: gpl, proprietary-code

I know nothing about GPL before, and I am living in a country that doesn't have much care about licenses either. I am studying this GPL thing today and I came to know that when I am using a GPLed library (no modifications to it) in my application and I am going to distribute this to others, then I am also obliged to distribute the source code as well.

But one thing I don't understand is, how will other people know that I am using GPLed libraries in my application?

If I can get a GPLed library, then that means I am able to get its source code. If I just copy pasted the source code to my application without nobody else knowing, how can others tell that I am using a GPLed library in my application then?

Comment: Depending on what you copy, it will show up in one way or another in the product you release. If you offer the source code, it will be fairly easy to see that you've copied it. Even if you only release the binaries, it will often be simple to see that you've copied.  For example, suppose you copy zlib in order to offer compression services. If I look at your binaries, I will be able to see zlib symbols (gzungetc, gzflush, etc.). There are ways to hide those symbols, but then there are still other ways to see that you've copied particular source code to make your binaries.

Comment: See also: [How do I spot and document a GPL violation?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80668/how-do-i-spot-and-document-a-gpl-violation)